# add sql statement condition on INNER JOIN only if the INNER JOIN record exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a row from a users table based on a condition in the join table ONLY if a record exists in the join table.  If the record does not exist, I want to return the row.  I only want to not return the row if an INNER JOIN record exists and the contact_blocked != 1.

With the statement below I achieve what I want when a users_to_users record exists and the value of contact_blocked = 0.  That row is returned.  When the contact is blocked nothing is returned.  That is all fine.  However, additionally when no INNER JOIN record yet exists, I still want to return the row with the user as they have not been blocked and no relation yet exists.  Not sure how to do that.

This is what I want without the join:

```
SELECT users.user_id 
FROM users
WHERE users.username = 'Danny Boy'
```

and here is what I want with the join:

```
SELECT users.user_id 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_to_users 
ON users.user_id = users_to_users.user_id 
AND users_to_users.contact_user_id ='123' 
WHERE users.username = 'Danny Boy' 
AND users_to_users.contact_blocked != 1
```

I want the join condition to apply only if a join record exists.  otherwise I would like the first case to apply.

EDIT

Desired Result.

If users_to_users record exists, only return the row for username 'Danny Boy' in users if users_to_users.contact_blocked != 1.

if users_to_users record does not exist, return the row for 'Danny Boy' in users

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Should you use LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT u.user_id 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     users_to_users utu
     ON u.user_id = utu.user_id AND utu.contact_user_id = '...' 
WHERE u.username = '...'  AND
      (utu.contact_blocked = 1 OR utu.contact_blocked IS NULL);
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks very much.  I tried this before but I put utu.contact_blocked = null instead of IS NULL.  Will accept as soon as it allows me in 8 minutes.  Thanks.  Also didn't know to use LEFT JOIN.